# How to batch get requests for Google Cloud Storage

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-storage

I would like to be able to collect a group of files all at once from a Google Cloud Storage bucket

At the moment all I am doing is getting the files one by one, however it is slow and my suspicion is that the network latency is the bottleneck here

Is there a way to batch the get requests, each file is really small so i feel like you should be able to collect collect them as a group

This is what I am currently doing

```py
client = storage.Client(project=project_id)
bucket = client.get_bucket(bucket_name)

blobs = []
for fname in fnames:
    blob = bucket.get_blob(fname)
    ob = blob.download_as_bytes()
    blobs.append(ob)

    # Other code to transform the data 
    # N.B. I will want to upload the data once it is transformed
```

Ideally there is some kind of batch function, or parameter i can pass through?

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve a [list of blobs](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/samples/storage-list-files-with-prefix#storage_list_files_with_prefix-python) in a bucket by a prefix, example :

```py
from google.cloud import storage


def list_blobs_with_prefix(bucket_name, prefix, delimiter=None):
    """Lists all the blobs in the bucket that begin with the prefix.

    This can be used to list all blobs in a "folder", e.g. "public/".

    The delimiter argument can be used to restrict the results to only the
    "files" in the given "folder". Without the delimiter, the entire tree under
    the prefix is returned. For example, given these blobs:

        a/1.txt
        a/b/2.txt

    If you specify prefix ='a/', without a delimiter, you'll get back:

        a/1.txt
        a/b/2.txt

    However, if you specify prefix='a/' and delimiter='/', you'll get back
    only the file directly under 'a/':

        a/1.txt

    As part of the response, you'll also get back a blobs.prefixes entity
    that lists the "subfolders" under `a/`:

        a/b/
    """

    storage_client = storage.Client()

    # Note: Client.list_blobs requires at least package version 1.17.0.
    blobs = storage_client.list_blobs(bucket_name, prefix=prefix, delimiter=delimiter)

    # Note: The call returns a response only when the iterator is consumed.
    print("Blobs:")
    for blob in blobs:
        print(blob.name)

    if delimiter:
        print("Prefixes:")
        for prefix in blobs.prefixes:
            print(prefix)
```

If needed you can also retrieve all the files in a bucket, then filter only the expected files :

```py
from google.cloud import storage


def list_blobs_with_prefix(bucket_name, prefix, delimiter=None):
    storage_client = storage.Client()

    blobs = storage_client.list_blobs(bucket_name)
    
    for blob in blobs:
        blob_name = blob.name
        # apply the filter on blob_name
    ....
```

Comment: Hey Mazlum, 

Thanks for this it is a neat way of getting all the blobs in an iterator at once (something I overlooked). 

However I am not sure this helps fully solve my initial issue as it still requires me to iterate through and download each blob as bytes individually. As I have to apply the download_as_bytes method each time. Is there a way to batch that method?